# How to describe a leak from a pipe

Tags: word-request

How to describe a leak from a pipe as is in the photo below at home or outside in more detailed way  Which words can be used besides leak?

[image]

https://acpfoto.com/photo/do-you-have-a-broken-water-line-or-leaking-water-main.html

Comment: Here's what immediately comes to my mind: **The water is gushing out of the pipe.**

Comment: @Michael Rybkin I was not sure if the word gush correct word because Google search mostly brought up  photos on which water is coming out of inside of  pipes that are much more bigger than that are used in homes.

Answer (score 2):

This particular fan- or cone-like pattern of high-velocity water is generally referred to as a "spray".

> The water is **spraying out** from a tear in the pipe.

See as reference various images of "spray nozzles" for garden or industrial applications:

[image]
[image]

Spray can also refer to water that has been mixed with air to form a kind of "mist", such as from a "spray bottle"

[image]

"Gush" implies the flow of a large quantity of water, but does not suggest any particular *pattern* or *shape*.

Comment: There's also "spewing".

Answer (score 0):

Yes spraying or gushing are words but they are vague and do not describe the size of the leak in detail. Take a bucket and fill for a minute, then measure the volume of water collected. The size of the leak can now be accurately described in litres or gallons per minute (g/pm or l/pm).

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! This site is about learning English, not DIY or physics. I think the last two sentences can be removed.